# How to use clang to generate all ast files for a project with makefile or cmakelist?

Tags: cmake, clang

I have developed a static analyze tool based on clang which reads all AST files generated by clang with `-emit-ast` option and then do analysis on them.

When testing the tool, it's very convenient to generate AST files for multiple c or cpp files. I can just use command like this one by one:

```
clang -emit-ast test.c -o test.ast
```

But when it comes to a large project which is build with make or cmake, I don't know how I can generate all the ast files.  Is there a convenient way to manage that?

Answer (score 3):

You can use [add_custom_target](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.4/command/add_custom_target.html) from CMake.

Something like this:

```
add_custom_target(ast)
foreach(SourceFile ${SourceFiles})
add_custom_command(TARGET ast PRE_BUILD
                 COMMAND clang -emit-ast ${SourceFile} -o ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/${SourceFile}.ast)
```

Answer (score 0):

Nice environment pre-build instructions. You can also embed this script into a *.ps file ... for more customization after a dry run is verified. A directory like "$(ProjectDir)\Scripts\my-scripts\script.ps" can be made in the pre-build and/ or any post build environment setting you may have. This is especially useful when administering a POSIX script that has to be enabled before or after the bash install process.